# Is binary search optimal given a "deadline"?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

Say we would like to find something not with average or worst case optimality, but given a deadline of iterations, we would like to optimize the probability of finding the target. Is binary search still optimal? Haven't been able to find anything online about this online and would love to see a proof or pseudo-proof.

Comment: That depends on your assumptions about the input, and what the "deadline" is relative to the size of the array. If your deadline is greater than `log_2 n` iterations then binary search meets the deadline with 100% probability; if it's less and the data is sampled from a uniform distribution, [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) is probably better. Having a "deadline" that you want to maximise the probability of meeting seems like an unusual scenario, and your scenario probably also includes other things that an algorithm might exploit.

Comment: If not a binary search, then what is the definition of "iteration"? For instance, a B-tree has two levels of iterations: the search for the B-tree node, and at each node the search in the node itself (constant time, given the block size).